# Not able to use parameter with dynamic placeholder

Tags: rendering-parameters

I am going through Sitecore training and currently stuck on module `working with component parameters`

Here I am trying to change the number of spaces by passing through a parameter.

Here is my code and also an ss of how I am trying to add parameter through `experience editor`:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue got resolved once I changed the additional parameter name to below as the placeholder name was "feature-spot" and not "feature_spot"

```
ph_feature-spot_count
```

> The parameters must follow a specific format:
>
> **ph_placeholderKey_paramName** where placeholderKey is the key in your
> code (customkey in last example) and paramName is the parameter name
> that will be passed through. Count is a special param name that
> defines the number of placeholders to generate.
>
> **ph_placeholderKey_indexNumber_paramName** where indexNumber is the
> placeholder index number. This allows you to only pass specific
> parameters to specific placeholders, e.g. If you wanted to pass a
> different CSS Class to the second placeholder to make it “featured”.
> Keep in mind that the number is 0 based.

Ref Url: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/sitecore-9-dynamic-placeholders/

Answer (score 1):

Could you please add `MaxCount`, just like below code and in [this link](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/sitecore-9-dynamic-placeholders/)?

```
@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder(new DynamicPlaceholderDefinition("placeholderkey")
    {
        Count = 3,
        MaxCount = 9,
        Seed = 9,
        OutputModifier = (input, context) => new HtmlString("<div class=\"large-4 small-12 columns\">" + input + "</div>"),
    })
```

also please confirm "ph_feature_spot_count" is a correct placeholder name.